# Many-to-many relationship on the same table using a junction table and a primary key in EF

Tags: entity-framework, many-to-many, primary-key

I have the following tables:

- `Sub_Option`: `Sub_Option_ID` as PK, `Name`
- `Sub_Option_To_Sub_Option`: `Sub_Option_To_Sub_Option_ID` as PK, `Sub_Option_ID_Primary`, `Sub_Option_ID_Secondary`

I would like to be able to access all the secondary sub options associated with the primary sub option via EF and vice-versa. Directly using `.Map` won't work as the junction table `Sub_Option_To_Sub_Option` has a primary key.

```
public class Sub_Option
{
    public int Sub_Option_ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

corresponding to Table

```
CREATE TABLE Sub_Option(
Sub_Option_ID int,
Name varchar(255)
);
```

and Table

```
CREATE TABLE Sub_Option_To_Sub_Option(
Sub_Option_To_Sub_Option int PK, 
Sub_Option_ID_Primary int,
Sub_Option_ID_Secondary int
);
```

Comment: Post te code and the mapping you have do and not working

Comment: Two virtual ICollection properties and map them many to many in fluent api i guess.

Comment: Added the structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work i think:

```
    public class OptionToOption
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PrimaryOption")]
    public int PrimaryID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("SecondaryOption")]
    public int SecondaryID { get; set; }

    public virtual Option PrimaryOption { get; set; }

    public virtual Option SecondaryOption { get; set; }
}

    public class Option
{
    public Option()
    {
        OptionToOption = new HashSet<OptionToOption>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<OptionToOption> OptionToOption { get; set; }
}
```

And in fluent api map like this (don't even think it's necessary to do this though):

```
            modelBuilder.Entity<Option>()
            .HasMany(e => e.OptionToOption)
            .WithRequired(e => e.PrimaryOption)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.PrimaryID);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Option>()
            .HasMany(e => e.OptionToOption)
            .WithRequired(e => e.SecondaryOption)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.SecondaryID);
```

Comment: To get for example all Secondaryoptions for primaryoption with ID = 5: var secondary = db.Options.Where(o => o.ID == 5).SelectMany(o => o.OptionToOption.Select(s => s.SecondaryOption).ToList();

Comment: You got it. Thank you!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, did you need the fluent api?